# How to set the keybinding for "Select All" to Ctrl-A?

Tags: key-bindings

I would normally be able to do this myself by merely adding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'select-all)
```

to my `~/.emacs` file but `select-all` isn't the command for the "Select All" option in the Edit menu (which selects all text in the current buffer). I have tried searching for "select" in the list of commands via pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and typing "select", but that did not return any result with "Select all" in its description. Any ideas? If it at all relevant I am using the experimental 25.1.90 release (the one tagged in the [`emacs-mirror/emacs`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs) GitHub repository) of GNU Emacs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mark-whole-buffer` is the command you want.  Here are some ways to discover it:

- <kbd><kbd>f1</kbd><kbd>c</kbd></kbd> (`describe-key`) works on menu items too.  In this case it would tell you

  ```
  <menu-bar> <edit> <mark-whole-buffer> runs the command mark-whole-buffer
  ```
- `mark-whole-buffer` is in the manual's index under "select all":
  <kbd><kbd>f1</kbd><kbd>r</kbd></kbd> to open the manual, <kbd><kbd>i</kbd>select all<kbd>RET</kbd></kbd> to check the index for "select all".

  > ‘C-x h’ (‘mark-whole-buffer’) sets up the entire buffer as the
  >   region, by putting point at the beginning and the mark at the end.